# Using Visual Studio's Syntax Highlighting Internal Data

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I want to create an Html syntax highlighter for C# and C/C++ and use the same color theme as Visual Studio. So, it is easy to write a simple tokenizer and highlight the text based on the output from the tokenizers. However, I want the highlighting quality to be at high level as Visual Studio has. Visual Studio can highlight the type names, function names and identifiers differently. I think it can do that with a means of symbol table and other parser/lexer genereated stuff.

Can I use Visual Studio's syntax highlighting data? Is there an API for this?

Comment: You could make a custom extension, the docs have details about what interfaces will help you do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/syntax-coloring-in-custom-editors

Comment: It seems the way to go but I have no experience in extension developing. So, I will switch back to the former method.

Comment: Out of curiosity where are you trying to have this syntax highlighting? This seems like a solved problem, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to change/add. The syntax highlighting for C, C++, and C# are fully implemented already.

Comment: I want to use the document data that VS builds to highlight the document in my website. I am planning to export this data somehow and use it to populate CSS rules to highlight the code in code tag that contains span tags marking up the individual language tokens. So, I don't want to add something to VS. My problem is not about that.